# postgresql: regexp_split_to_table - how to split text by delimiters

Tags: regex, postgresql, regexp-replace

I need to split my text to table by delimiters `'<='` and `'=>'`, for example

```
select regexp_split_to_table('kik plz <= p1 => and <= p2 => too. A say <=p1 =>','regexp');
```

The result must be:

```
table:
--------------
1 | 'kik plz '
2 | '<= p1 =>'
3 | ' and '
4 | <= p2 =>
5 | ' too. A say '
6 | '<=p1 =>'
```

I think the answer is in positional patterns, but my skills are not enough.

```
select regexp_split_to_table('kik plz <= p1 => and <= p2 => too. A say <=p1 =>', '((\s)(?=<=))|((\s)(?!=>))')
```

This returns the wrong result.

Comment: right example    

'select regexp_split_to_table('kik plz<= p1 => and <= p2 => too. A say <=p1 =>','regexp');'

Answer (score 1):

```
select regexp_split_to_table(
    replace(
        replace('kik plz<= p1 =>and<= p2 =>too. A say <=p1 =>',  '<=',  E'\001<=')
    , '=>', E'=>\001')
, E'\001');
```