# using postgresql to split a regex, returning the results AND the delimiters

Tags: regex, postgresql

I'm using Postgres, server version 14.8, and I'd like to parse a string, returning both the strings that sit between the regexp delimiter AND the delimiters too.

Typically in a language such as Java, Perl, etc,  I would get the delimiters using back references, but I'm not sure how to do this with Postgres SQL.

Here's what I have, using the function regexp_split_to_table:

and the regular expression: '[(.+?)]'

```
select regexp_split_to_table('IF [Cost_1]=0 THEN ''[$0]'' ELSEIF [Cost_2]>0 AND [Cost_1]<=100 THEN ''[$1,$100]'' ELSE ''[$0]'' END', '\[(.+?)\]');
```

And the output:

```
regexp_split_to_table 
-----------------------
 IF 
 =0 THEN '
 ' ELSEIF 
 >0 AND 
 <=100 THEN '
 ' ELSE '
 ' END
(7 rows)
```

But what I would like would be something like this, which includes the delimiters, interleaved:

```
regexp_split_to_table
-----------------------
 IF
 [Cost_1]
 =0 THEN '
 [$0]
 ' ELSEIF
 [Cost_2]
 >0 AND
 [Cost_1]
 <=100 THEN '
 [$1,$100]
' ELSE '
 [$0]
' END
(13 rows)
```

Using this function , or any other Postgresql function(s) available in 14.8, how do I do this?

Thank you,
Anthony

Answer (score 1):

Looking at this link, [postgresql: regexp_split_to_table - how to split text by delimiters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34295427/postgresql-regexp-split-to-table-how-to-split-text-by-delimiters), this variation works:

```
select regexp_split_to_table(
       replace(
        replace('IF [Cost_1]=0 THEN ''[$0]'' ELSEIF [Cost_2]>0 AND [Cost_1]<=100 THEN ''[$1,$100]'' ELSE ''[$0]'' END',  '[', E'\001[')
    , ']', E']\001')
  ,E'\001');
```